# PHP - Loopless way to split a string into a single array?

Tags: php

Hello guys i try to split a big string with dates to a single array.

It looks like that and is very big:

```
string(715383) "13/01/201618/01/201618/01/201618/01/201618/01/201601/02/201601/02/201602/02/201605/02/201605/02/201608/02/201615/02/201615/02/201615/02/201615/02/2016"
```

I split the string with `str_split` and tried to `implode` it, but I get the same length of string.

```
$dateArray = str_split($dateWorked, 10);
```

My output from str_split is that

```
array(71539) { 
[0]=> string(10) "13/01/2016" 
[1]=> string(10) "18/01/2016" 
[2]=> string(10) "18/01/2016" 
[3]=> string(10) "18/01/2016" 
[4]=> string(10) "18/01/2016" 
}
```

My desired output is that:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "04/08/2021" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "04/08/2021" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "04/08/2021" }
```

Even perfect result would be to split the big chunk of string to smaller strings like normal Date `string(10) "13/01/2016"`.

```
$dateWorked= "";
$startTime  = 0;
$endTime    = 0;
$itemPacked = 0; 
$perMin     = 0.75;
$pickedRate = 0; 
$precentEff = 100;
$preCal     = 0; 
$sumArray = array();
$sumArray1 = array();
$out = fopen('packingresults.csv', 'w+', ',');

echo "<table class=\"firstable\" style=\"border: 1px solid lightgrey; border-collapse: collapse;\"> \n\n";
$row = 0;
if (($handle = fopen("picking.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $row++;
        if($row == 1) continue;
        
        $empWorked          = $data[Name];
        $dateWorked         .= "".$data[0];
        $startTime          = $data[Start];
        $endTime            = $data[Finish];
        $itemPacked         = $data[Item];
        $nameEmp            = $data[Employee];
        $startParts         = explode(":", $startTime);
        $endParts           = explode(":", $endTime);
        $startMinute        = (int)$startParts[1];
        $startHour          = (int)$startParts[0];
        $endMinute          = (int)$endParts[1];
        $endHour            = (int)$endParts[0];
        $differenceHour     = ($endHour - $startHour);
        $differenceMinute   = ($endMinute - $startMinute);
        $differenceHour     -= (($differenceMinute < 0) ? 1 : 0);
        
        if ($differenceMinute < 0) $differenceMinute += 60;
        
        $difference = $differenceHour * 60 + $differenceMinute;
        $sumArray[$data[0]."_".$data[1].'_'.$data[5]] += $data[4];
        $sumArray1[$data[0]."_".$data[1].'_'.$data[5]] += $difference;
    }
} 

// I take out $dateWorked out from while loop and its come in big ching of string instead of separated strings.

$arr = array_map(function($v){return [$v];}, str_split($dateWorked , 10));

var_dump($arr);

$result =[];
$newArray = array();
foreach($sumArray as $key => $totalItems)
{
    $fileDate = array();
    $from_date = $_POST['fromdate'];
    $to_date =  $_POST['todate'];

    $result[$totalItems][ ]= $sumArray1[$key];
    $minuteTotal = implode(" ", $result[$totalItems]);
    list($date1,$id1, $name1) = explode('_', $key);
    $timePicked = explode(" " ,$sumArray1[$key]);
    $timePickedCon  =  implode(" ", $timePicked); 
    $dateCon = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace("/","-",$date)));
    $dateCon1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace("/","-",$date1)));

    $procenti = round(($perMin*$totalItems)/($timePickedCon/$precentEff),2);
    
    if($dateCon1 >= $from_date && $dateCon1 <= $to_date){ 
        $fileDate[] = $date1;
    }
    
    //var_dump($fileDate);
    if (in_array($date1, $fileDate)) {
        //var_dump($fileDate);
        //echo "<br>  ". $name. " ".$totalItems. " ".$procenti."%";
        //$pickingEffRes = [$name , $totalItems, $procenti];
        //fputcsv($out, $pickingEffRes);
    }
}
fclose($handle);
$fclose($out);
```

Comment: Why an array of arrays of one element, instead of an array of `n` elements?

Comment: I'm confused -- what's wrong with your `str_split()` line? It makes an array where each element is one date.

Comment: @AlexHowansky because the array looks like that `array(71539) { [0]=> string(10) "13/01/2016" [1]=> string(10) "18/01/2016" [2]=> string(10) "18/01/2016" [3]=> string(10) "18/01/2016" [4]=>`

Comment: @JamesWebster  because i took this elemnt out of while loop i need it outside of the while loop .

Comment: I think you just need to move your split outside of the while - we might need to see more of your code in this case.

Comment: It's a veri big code , my split is already outside of the while loop. 
`$dateWorked    .= "".$data[0];`    i get this in while loop and after that i taking it out from the loop and split it outside

Comment: Maybe a regex for your date formats, `(?:0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01])/(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/(?:(?:19|20)\d{2})`?

Comment: I don't understand, what exactly do you want? in a one liner you do: $array = str_split($string,10); and this will create an array divided to dates from the string. in your question you talk about getting an array with each key 0?! whats the difference or wrong with the $array = str_split($string,10);?

Comment: So you want a multidimensional array?

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to ask why you have this awful data to work with. Surely no one is transmitting data this way. And if the source is your own code, then fix the structuring of the data as you acquire it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd keep your str_split idea :

```
$dateArray = str_split($dateWorked, 10);
```

And then apply the [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) php function to extract each date :

```
array_walk($dateArray, function($a){array_slice($a, 0, 1);var_dump($a);});
```

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you correctly you want to get each date into a separate array, which just isn't possible currently as you cannot assign multiple references to a single variable, which is what you'd basically like to achieve. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

This would come close to your desired output (thank you Balázs Varga for your snippet):

```
list($date1, $date2, $date3, ...) = array_map(function($v){return [$v];}, str_split($str, 10));
```

Each Variable would contain the following output (same values just for presentation purposes):

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "04/08/2021" } // output of $date1
array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "04/08/2021" } // output of $date2
array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "04/08/2021" } // output of $date3
```

Comment: thank you , but my file have 70k+ dates . i can't asign like 70k vars

Comment: @stoperan - no, but you can have an array with ~70k elements and use that - which is what you have after the str_split

Answer (score 1):

While this does not answer the question in your post title, looking at your code, it seems that you are concatenating $dateWorked in the while loop, only to then split it after the while loop.

```
$dateWorked .= "".$data[0];
```

So why not just build the array you want in the while loop instead of concatenating and then splitting $dateWorked?  Then there is no need to process $dateWorked outside the loop.  And, you may not need $dateWorked if this is its only purpose.

One option would be this in the while loop:

```
$arr[] = $data[0];
```

That results in an array of 71539 string items.

If you really want an array of arrays each with 1 element then try this in the while loop:

```
$arr[$row-2][] = $data[0];
```

That would result in an array of 71539 array items.  each array item with 1 string item.

To decouple the $arr from $row (in case in the future you don't skip the first line) initialize a counter to 0 and use that for the arr count

```
$arr[$arrCount++][] = $data[0];
```

In each case, initialize $arr before the while loop just to be safe:

```
$arr = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why do you need a multidimensional array, and how/where do you get that terribly "formatted" data, but your desired output can be achieved by an [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map).

```
$arr = array_map(function($v){return [$v];}, str_split($str, 10));
```

This will wrap all of the values into another array in one line.

Comment: i still get the arrays inside of an array , my goal its to take out this data outside of this big chunk `array(71539) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "13/01/2016" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "18/01/2016" } [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "18/01/2016" } [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "18/01/2016" } [4]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "18/01/2016" } [5]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "01/02/2016" } [6]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "01/02/2016" } [7]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "02/02/2016" } `

Comment: I don't undertand how do you want to approach that... I mean, where would your arrays go then? You must store them in some variable.

Comment: It's store in variable which is in while loop. But i took this  variable otside the loop `if(($handle = fopen("picking.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $row++;

 if($row == 1) continue;
        $empWorked    = $data[Name];
        $dateWorked    .= "".$data[0];`

Comment: I don't understand what your code does as it is incomplete and has syntax errors. Can you provide a full example to better understand what you're trying to do? What you provide in your "desired output" section is 3 array without a variable/name, which is simply impossible.

Comment: i edit the question now you can see the whole code

Comment: Maybe you simply need to change ```$dateWorked= "";``` to ```$dateWorked= [];```, and ```$dateWorked    .= "".$data[0];``` to ```$dateWorked[] = $data[0];``` ? Then you'll have an array instead of a big string.

Comment: i get the same array `array(71539) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "13/01/2016" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "18/01/2016" } [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "18/01/2016" } [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "18/01/2016" } [4]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "18/01/2016" } [5]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "01/02/2016" } [6]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "01/02/2016" } [7]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "02/02/2016" }`

Comment: Then I really don't know what you expect. What you described as your "desired output" makes no sense... That's 3 separate arrays, in the void, without a variable... That's impossible not just in PHP but like any programming language. You MUST have an array, or some variable to hold your values.

Answer (score 0):

**The simplest way using regex**

```
$res = preg_match_all("/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/", $yourString, $matches); 
print_r($matches[0]);
        [0] => 13/01/2016
        [1] => 18/01/2016
        [2] => 18/01/2016
        [3] => 18/01/2016
```

**This regex means** 2digit/2digit/4digit